# Accuracy of MongoDB Intersect Query

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, postgis

I read somewhere that MongoDB doesn't accurately do spatial searches, as it creates a bounding box around the objects and checks if they intersect, rather than checking whether the original shapes actually intersect. Annoyingly I can't find this webpage again.

Has anyone else had this experience?

UPDATE:
I'm trying to decide whether to use MongoDb or PostGis for a scalable web system (Java Spring-Boot back-end), which requires accurate intersection queries.  So for PostGis I'd probably use ST_Overlaps, and for MongoDb $geoIntersects.  I will also use the spatially near functions however their accuracy isn't so important.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-30-features-big-polygon - is this the topic you mean?

Comment: And here the related documentation part: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#geowithin-big-poly

Comment: Ot this one: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/geospatial-performance-improvements-in-mongodb-3-2

Comment: It was similar to the mongodb.com/blog/post but for $geoIntersects or $geowithin. That is it wasn't that accurate. I've tried to find out some accuracy information on these two queries but can't see anything.